# why trying to deference void pointer does not work?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main()
{
    int b = 12;
    void *ptr = &b;
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected for this code to print 12, but it does not.
if instead of void pointer, we define int pointer it would work.
I wanted to know how can we use void pointer and print the address allocated to it and the amount saved in it?

Comment: Because dereferencing `void*` would be `void`, which is an "incomplete" type. That is, the compiler has no idea what to do with it.

Comment: so what is use of void pointer? because we can never have access to its deference

Comment: `void` *pointer* has a lot of uses, because as a *pointer* it is compatible with any other pointer type, which *can* be dereferenced.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So here if I refer void pointer to another datatype then I can print the content.How can it be done?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Qualification: "because as a pointer it is compatible with any other pointer type," s/b any other object type.  Roundtripping a `void*` through a function pointer is not specified to work.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Right

Comment: "how can we use void pointer and print the address allocated to it and the amount saved in it?" --> by casting to `void *`, the " amount saved in it" (the original pointer) is lost.

Comment: @sajjadeshghi Is your question answered by dbush ?

Comment: Have a look at examples of how to write a compare function for `qsort` and you'll see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

void pointers cannot be dereferenced.it will give this warning

**Compiler Error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type**

so, you have to do it like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int b = 12;
    void *ptr = &b;
    printf("%d", *(int *)ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Dereferencing a `void *` doesn't make sense because it has no way of knowing the type of the memory it points to.

You would need to cast to pointer to a `int *` and then dereference it.

```
printf("%d", *((int *)ptr));
```

Comment: *" because it has no way of knowing the type of the memory it points to."* By *"it"* do you mean the compiler?

Comment: @MehdiCharife Yes, the compiler has no information regarding what kind of data a `void *` points to.

Answer (score 2):

A schoolbook example of when void pointers are useful is `qsort`.

This is the signature:

```
void qsort(void *base, 
           size_t nitems, 
           size_t size, 
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void*)
          );
```

`base` is just a pointer to the first element. The reason it's a void pointer is because qsort can be used for any list, regardless of type. `nitems` is number of items (doh) in the list, and `size` is the size of each element. Nothing strange so far.

But it does also take a fourth argument, which is a function pointer. You're supposed to write a custom compare function and pass a pointer to this function. This is what makes `qsort` able to sort any list. But since it's supposed to be generic, it takes two void pointers as argument. Here is an example of such a compare function, which is a bit bloated for clarity:

```
int cmpfloat(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const float *aa = (float*) a;
    const float *bb = (float*) b;

    if(*aa == *bb) {
        return 0;
    } else if(*aa > *bb)  {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Pretty clear what is going on. It returns positive number if a>b, zero if they are equal and negative if b>a, which is the requirements. In reality, I'd just write it like this:

```
int cmpfloat(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(float*)a - *(float*)b;
}
```

What you do with this is something like:

```
float arr[5] = {5.1, 3.4, 8.9, 3.4, 1.3};
qsort(arr, 5, sizeof *arr, cmpfloat);
```

Maybe it's not completely accurate to say that void pointers are used instead of templates, generic functions, overloaded functions and such, but they have similarities.

Answer (score 2):

If `p` has type `void *`, then the expression `*p` has type `void`, which means "no value".  You can't pass a `void` expression to `printf` for the `%d` conversion specifier (or any other conversion specifier).

In order to dereference a `void *`, you must first convert it to a pointer of the appropriate type.  You can do it with a cast:

```
printf( "%d\n", *(int *) ptr );
```

or assign it to a pointer of the appropriate type:

```
int *p = ptr;
printf( "%d\n", *p );
```

The rules around `void` pointers are special such that they can be assigned to other pointer types without an explicit cast - this allows them to be used as a "generic" pointer type.  However, you cannot directly examine the thing a `void` pointer points to.